# how to use gulp-usemin in twig

Tags: symfony, gulp, twig, gulp-usemin

I'm trying to use gulp-usemin to do asset management for my twig files in order to replace assetic. Can I do so while still maintaining the asset() methods advantages to find the relative path of my assets?

Comment: `asset()` in Twig is not provided by assetic.

Comment: @PatrikKarisch Yes, I realize that asset() is not provided by assetic, what I mean to say is I am not sure if gulp-usemin is capable of parsing a twig file with the link provided using twigs asset method and if not how I might do so

Answer (score 0):

`Asset` is a Symfony component that was introduced in `2.7`, see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset/introduction.html

So, yes you can use the asset component standalone.

Comment: Twigs `asset()` is not the same as the Asset component

Comment: It actually is the Asset component, given that the `asset()` filter can be found in the `TwigBridge` at the `AssetExtension` that is directly making use of the Asset component. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/AssetExtension.php#L17

Comment: Ok ^^. But only since 2.7. before `asset()` was not a own component :P